# How can I export Scala Spark DataFrames schema to a Json file?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried `df.write.json("myNewJson")`which although does not throws any error or warning it simply doesn't create any file in the target. `df.write.format("json").save("/MyDir/")` also seems to have the same problem. Am I missing some statement here?

Comment: does `df.show()` shows you results?

Comment: I may not understand the question completely, but to convert any schema to json you can do: 

df.schema.json. 

This will give you a json, which you can export or use for whatever you need

Comment: Hi @RameshMaharjan, checked df.show() , it displayed all the records..

Comment: thank you @SCouto , this helps..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Posting the exact code that worked for me for those who might stumble upon the same problem..
I was able to export a DataFrame schema to Json file using the below statements:

```
import java.io._

val a = df.schema.json
val writer = new PrintWriter(new File("/home/file"))
writer.write(a)
writer.close()
```

Comment: is it possible to do in python?

Answer (score 0):

`df.write` are for saving of **content** of the df, while `df.schema` is for the **structure** of the df. Your DataFrame is probably empty. You can check it by `df.show()` before saving.

Comment: checked df.show() , it displayed all the records.. However i was able to export the df schema to a file using the statement provided by @SCouto above.